# solr DIH: Generate identity value

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I need to import my database data into solr.

I'm using this `data-config.xml`:

```
<dataConfig>

  <dataSource driver="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" url="jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.122.1;databaseName=giac_txt" user="sa" password="StR0nGp4ss."/> 

  <document>

    <entity name="item" query="select codi_unitat, titol from anc_uniciac>
      <field column="codi_unitat" name="code_l_ns"/>
      <field column="titol" name="title_txt_ca" />
    </entity>

  </document>

</dataConfig>
```

Problem arises when I need to generate an id, since my schema needs and id:

```
<schema name="example-data-driven-schema" version="1.6">
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
   ...
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I've checked on `solrconfig.xml`:

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="files-update-processor">
    <!-- UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory will generate an id if none is present in the incoming document -->
    <processor class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory" />
```

And it's linked by default on any `update`:

```
<initParams path="/update/**">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="update.chain">files-update-processor</str>
  </lst>
</initParams>
```

Does it means that an uuid is generated by default?

Comment: DOes the data from table anc_uniciac have any id field? if yes map the same to id field. If you dont have id field in the database table you can generate it by configuring it with UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory in the solrconfig.xml

Answer (score 0):

`UUID` is short for Universal Unique IDentifier. You can use if it if you dont have the id for the documents inserted in solr.

The `unique id` field is useful when you need to update or delete a document, because regular searches in Solr can't uniquely identify a document.

Add the below configuration in the `solrconfig.xml`.

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain>
 
    <processor class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory">
      <str name="fieldName">id</str>
    </processor>
 
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
  </updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

Comment: Should I need to link this chain into my updatehandler?

Comment: you can add it under the Update Processors list...where all the update processors are mentioned